# Server shutting down for no reason, kernel errors. Please advice

Tags: linux, centos, kernel

My server has being shutting down by itself for the last 3 days after a power related problem. It's a KVM virtual machine. It stays on for no longer than about 20 minutes then it turns off. Note that it doesn't restart, only shut down.

This is what I see in my `/var/log/messages`:

```
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.493252] pci 0000:00:01.2: PCI INT D disabled
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.493726] Trying to unpack rootfs image as initramfs...
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.654652] Freeing initrd memory: 13639k freed
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.657174] audit: initializing netlink socket (disabled)
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.657664] type=2000 audit(1389774593.656:1): initialized
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.664657] HugeTLB registered 2 MB page size, pre-allocated 0 pages
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.666315] VFS: Disk quotas dquot_6.5.2
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.666765] Dquot-cache hash table entries: 512 (order 0, 4096 bytes)
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.667385] msgmni has been set to 19986
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.668629] alg: No test for stdrng (krng)
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.669102] ksign: Installing public key data
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.669539] Loading keyring
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.669923] - Added public key AE95AE35994EC460
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.670362] - User ID: Red Hat, Inc. (Kernel Module GPG key)
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.670829] - Added public key D4A26C9CCD09BEDA
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.671263] - User ID: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Driver Update Program <secalert@redhat.com>
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.672074] - Added public key 86270BD1D73862D7
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.672510] - User ID: Parallels, Inc. (Kernel Module GPG key)
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.673025] Block layer SCSI generic (bsg) driver version 0.4 loaded (major 251)
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.674444] io scheduler noop registered
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.674857] io scheduler anticipatory registered
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.675298] io scheduler deadline registered
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.675780] io scheduler cfq registered (default)
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.676296] pci_hotplug: PCI Hot Plug PCI Core version: 0.5
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.676769] pciehp: PCI Express Hot Plug Controller Driver version: 0.4
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.677266] acpiphp: ACPI Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.5
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.677798] acpiphp: Slot [1] registered
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.678227] acpiphp: Slot [2] registered
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.678651] acpiphp: Slot [3] registered
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.679072] acpiphp: Slot [4] registered
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.679502] acpiphp: Slot [5] registered
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.679924] acpiphp: Slot [6] registered
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.680353] acpiphp: Slot [7] registered
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.680774] acpiphp: Slot [8] registered
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.681194] acpiphp: Slot [9] registered
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.681625] acpiphp: Slot [10] registered
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.682049] acpiphp: Slot [11] registered
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.682481] acpiphp: Slot [12] registered
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.682905] acpiphp: Slot [13] registered
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.683341] acpiphp: Slot [14] registered
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.683765] acpiphp: Slot [15] registered
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.684189] acpiphp: Slot [16] registered
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.684622] acpiphp: Slot [17] registered
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.685045] acpiphp: Slot [18] registered
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.685479] acpiphp: Slot [19] registered
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.685903] acpiphp: Slot [20] registered
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.686336] acpiphp: Slot [21] registered
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.686759] acpiphp: Slot [22] registered
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.687184] acpiphp: Slot [23] registered
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.687618] acpiphp: Slot [24] registered
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.688042] acpiphp: Slot [25] registered
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.688474] acpiphp: Slot [26] registered
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.688897] acpiphp: Slot [27] registered
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.689330] acpiphp: Slot [28] registered
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.689754] acpiphp: Slot [29] registered
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.690177] acpiphp: Slot [30] registered
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.690611] acpiphp: Slot [31] registered
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.691550] ipmi message handler version 39.2
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.691983] IPMI System Interface driver.
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.692421] ipmi_si: Adding default-specified kcs state machine
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.692928] ipmi_si: Trying default-specified kcs state machine at i/o address 0xca2, slave address 0x0, irq 0
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.693800] ipmi_si: Interface detection failed
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.699259] ipmi_si: Adding default-specified smic state machine
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.699772] ipmi_si: Trying default-specified smic state machine at i/o address 0xca9, slave address 0x0, irq 0
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.700641] ipmi_si: Interface detection failed
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.711250] ipmi_si: Adding default-specified bt state machine
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.779566] ipmi_si: Trying default-specified bt state machine at i/o address 0xe4, slave address 0x0, irq 0
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.780433] ipmi_si: Interface detection failed
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.784271] ipmi_si: Unable to find any System Interface(s)
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.784792] input: Power Button as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input0
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.785584] ACPI: Power Button [PWRF]
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.787946] ERST: Table is not found!
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.788362] GHES: HEST is not enabled!
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.790335] Non-volatile memory driver v1.3
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.790759] Linux agpgart interface v0.103
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.791257] crash memory driver: version 1.1
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.791684] Serial: 8250/16550 driver, 4 ports, IRQ sharing enabled
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.792911] brd: module loaded
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.793596] loop: module loaded
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.794005] input: Macintosh mouse button emulation as /devices/virtual/input/input1
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.794832] Fixed MDIO Bus: probed
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.795256] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.795763] ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.796252] uhci_hcd: USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.796788] uhci_hcd 0000:00:01.2: PCI INT D -> Link[LNKD] -> GSI 11 (level, high) -> IRQ 11
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.797622] uhci_hcd 0000:00:01.2: UHCI Host Controller
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.798098] uhci_hcd 0000:00:01.2: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.798956] uhci_hcd 0000:00:01.2: irq 11, io base 0x0000c020
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.799463] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0001
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.799981] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.800770] usb usb1: Product: UHCI Host Controller
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.801209] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 2.6.32-458.23.2.lve1.2.48.el6.x86_64 uhci_hcd
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.802030] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:01.2
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.802525] usb usb1: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.803005] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.803424] hub 1-0:1.0: 2 ports detected
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.803911] PNP: PS/2 Controller [PNP0303:KBD,PNP0f13:MOU] at 0x60,0x64 irq 1,12
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.805200] serio: i8042 KBD port at 0x60,0x64 irq 1
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.805674] serio: i8042 AUX port at 0x60,0x64 irq 12
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.806214] mice: PS/2 mouse device common for all mice
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.806811] rtc_cmos 00:01: RTC can wake from S4
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.807359] rtc_cmos 00:01: rtc core: registered rtc_cmos as rtc0
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.807453] input: AT Translated Set 2 keyboard as /devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input2
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.808850] rtc0: alarms up to one day, 114 bytes nvram
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.809383] cpuidle: using governor ladder
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.809913] cpuidle: using governor menu
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.810422] EFI Variables Facility v0.08 2004-May-17
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.811320] usbcore: registered new interface driver hiddev
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.811849] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.812396] usbhid: v2.6:USB HID core driver
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.812981] TCP cubic registered
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.813484] Initializing XFRM netlink socket
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.814001] NET: Registered protocol family 17
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.819268] Dcache charge unit 924
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.910120] registered taskstats version 1
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.914569] rtc_cmos 00:01: setting system clock to 2014-01-15 08:29:52 UTC (1389774592)
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.915419] Initalizing network drop monitor service
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.915902] Freeing unused kernel memory: 1328k freed
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.916458] Write protecting the kernel read-only data: 10240k
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.917209] Freeing unused kernel memory: 860k freed
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.917864] Freeing unused kernel memory: 1660k freed
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.925405] dracut: dracut-004-336.el6_5.2
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    0.930220] udev: starting version 147
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    1.040937] dracut: Starting plymouth daemon
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    1.132111] usb 1-1: new full speed USB device number 2 using uhci_hcd
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    1.231298] scsi0 : ata_piix
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    1.231864] scsi1 : ata_piix
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    1.232282] ata1: PATA max MWDMA2 cmd 0x1f0 ctl 0x3f6 bmdma 0xc000 irq 14
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    1.232821] ata2: PATA max MWDMA2 cmd 0x170 ctl 0x376 bmdma 0xc008 irq 15
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    1.260166] input: ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse as /devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input3
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    1.393906] ata2.00: ATAPI: QEMU DVD-ROM, 0.12.1, max UDMA/100
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    1.394681] ata2.00: configured for MWDMA2
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    1.395524] scsi 1:0:0:0: CD-ROM            QEMU     QEMU DVD-ROM     0.12 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    1.409705] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKC] enabled at IRQ 10
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    1.410451] virtio-pci 0000:00:03.0: PCI INT A -> Link[LNKC] -> GSI 10 (level, high) -> IRQ 10
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    1.411864] virtio-pci 0000:00:04.0: PCI INT A -> Link[LNKD] -> GSI 11 (level, high) -> IRQ 11
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    1.413348] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKA] enabled at IRQ 10
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    1.413858] virtio-pci 0000:00:05.0: PCI INT A -> Link[LNKA] -> GSI 10 (level, high) -> IRQ 10
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    1.414916] ACPI: PCI Interrupt Link [LNKB] enabled at IRQ 11
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    1.415406] virtio-pci 0000:00:06.0: PCI INT A -> Link[LNKB] -> GSI 11 (level, high) -> IRQ 11
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    1.548212] sr0: scsi3-mmc drive: 4x/4x xa/form2 tray
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    1.548214] Uniform CD-ROM driver Revision: 3.20
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    1.577573]  vda: vda1 vda2
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    1.594718]  vdb: unknown partition table
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    1.616493] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0627, idProduct=0001
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    1.616497] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=3, SerialNumber=5
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    1.616500] usb 1-1: Product: QEMU USB Tablet
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    1.616502] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: QEMU 0.12.1
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    1.616504] usb 1-1: SerialNumber: 42
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    1.616546] usb 1-1: configuration #1 chosen from 1 choice
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    1.633520] input: QEMU 0.12.1 QEMU USB Tablet as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.2/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/input/input4
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    1.634464] generic-usb 0003:0627:0001.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v0.01 Pointer [QEMU 0.12.1 QEMU USB Tablet] on usb-0000:00:01.2-1/input0
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    1.656057] Refined TSC clocksource calibration: 3292.375 MHz.
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    1.873617] EXT4-fs (vda2): INFO: recovery required on readonly filesystem
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    1.874203] EXT4-fs (vda2): write access will be enabled during recovery
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    2.018722] EXT4-fs (vda2): recovery complete
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    2.027241] EXT4-fs (vda2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: 
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    2.164743] dracut: Remounting /dev/disk/by-uuid/b8ee1c9e-0409-4008-9fa0-15c9735ba7dd with -o usrjquota=quota.user,jqfmt=vfsv0,ro
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    2.297625] EXT4-fs (vda2): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: 
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    2.430865] dracut: Mounted root filesystem /dev/vda2
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    2.775378] dracut: /sbin/load_policy: Can't load policy: No such device
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    2.966526] dracut: Switching root
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    4.085183] udev: starting version 147
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    4.350677] sr 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 5
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    4.575883] piix4_smbus 0000:00:01.3: SMBus Host Controller at 0xb100, revision 0
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    4.827194] device-mapper: uevent: version 1.0.3
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    4.827925] device-mapper: ioctl: 4.23.6-ioctl (2012-07-25) initialised: dm-devel@redhat.com
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    5.528314] EXT4-fs (vda1): mounted filesystem with ordered data mode. Opts: 
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    8.623480] NET: Registered protocol family 10
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    8.636528] ip6_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    8.720707] Enabling conntracks and NAT for ve0
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    8.791253] nf_conntrack version 0.5.0 (16384 buckets, 65536 max)
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    8.858319] iolimits: module license 'CloudLinux Commercial License' taints kernel.
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    8.859156] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    8.859915] iolimits version 0.1-93.el6
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    8.871667] io_set_limit = ffffffffa01a8820
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    8.872115] io_get_usage = ffffffffa01a8610
Jan 15 06:30:08 us01 kernel: [    8.873380] lve driver register status 0
Jan 15 06:30:09 us01 kernel: [   18.009055] tun: Universal TUN/TAP device driver, 1.6
Jan 15 06:30:09 us01 kernel: [   18.009546] tun: (C) 1999-2004 Max Krasnyansky <maxk@qualcomm.com>
Jan 15 06:30:57 us01 varnishd[1876]: Platform: Linux,2.6.32-458.23.2.lve1.2.48.el6.x86_64,x86_64,-sfile,-smalloc,-hcritbit
Jan 15 06:30:57 us01 varnishd[1876]: child (1877) Started
Jan 15 06:30:57 us01 varnishd[1876]: Child (1877) said Child starts
Jan 15 06:30:57 us01 varnishd[1876]: Child (1877) said SMF.s0 mmap'ed 1572864000 bytes of 1572864000
Jan 15 06:30:57 us01 fail2ban.server : INFO   Changed logging target to SYSLOG for Fail2ban v0.8.11
Jan 15 06:30:57 us01 fail2ban.jail   : INFO   Creating new jail 'ssh-iptables'
Jan 15 06:30:58 us01 fail2ban.jail   : INFO   Jail 'ssh-iptables' uses pyinotify
Jan 15 06:30:58 us01 fail2ban.jail   : INFO   Initiated 'pyinotify' backend
Jan 15 06:30:58 us01 fail2ban.filter : INFO   Added logfile = /var/log/secure
Jan 15 06:30:58 us01 fail2ban.filter : INFO   Set maxRetry = 5
Jan 15 06:30:58 us01 fail2ban.filter : INFO   Set findtime = 600
Jan 15 06:30:58 us01 fail2ban.actions: INFO   Set banTime = 600
Jan 15 06:30:58 us01 fail2ban.jail   : INFO   Jail 'ssh-iptables' started
Jan 15 06:30:58 us01 kernel: [   66.771098] ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
Jan 15 06:31:06 us01 rhnsd[2563]: Red Hat Network Services Daemon starting up, check in interval 240 minutes.
Jan 14 22:31:22 us01 kernel: [   79.092649] hrtimer: interrupt took 2664381 ns
Jan 14 22:31:23 us01 kernel: [   79.910823] Fatal resource shortage: privvmpages, UB 627.
Jan 14 22:31:23 us01 kernel: [   79.911036] Fatal resource shortage: privvmpages, UB 627.
Jan 14 22:31:23 us01 kernel: [   79.911242] Fatal resource shortage: privvmpages, UB 627.
Jan 14 22:31:23 us01 kernel: [   79.912705] Fatal resource shortage: privvmpages, UB 627.
```

There's a lot of kernel related stuff. Would someone have any suggestion for what may be causing this problem?

Some more extensive information from /var/log/messages is pasted here: http://pastebin.com/bcTzcs0J

Thank you.

Comment: What Linux distribution is this? What third party software did you install?

Comment: CentOS 6.5 | Installed CloudLinux

Comment: So the host is CentOS and the kvm guest is CloudLinux. The VM that is shutting down and that you're showing logs from is CloudLinux. CloudLinux is hosting its own guests via OpenVZ. I believe the "fatal resource shortage" messages refer to those.

Comment: @sciurus this is what is getting me confused. The VM (guest) is **KVM**  based, and it has Cloudlinux + cPanel installed, which are based on CentOS. The host is Debian. There's no OpenVZ guest, and usually privvmpages errors are related to OpenVZ. Cloudlinux is software that let us set limits to individual users. All the logs above are from the KVM guest.

Comment: I thought CloudLinux was based on OpenVZ; I guess I was mistaken. What I've seen of their documentation isn't very clear on the underlying tech.

Comment: Dumping your entire log file on us (useless, by the way except *possibly* `Fatal resource shortage: privvmpages, UB 627.` - Didjya Google it?) is ***INCREDIBLY bad form***. Have you done any troubleshooting? [Go take a look here for some advice on the *BARE MINIMUM* amount of effort you should be putting forth](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault). I'm not trying to be mean, but you really need to put in ***SOME*** effort...

Answer (score 1):

Try running `lveinfo --period=1d --by-fault=mem --display-username`

Find out what `privvmpages` is set to currently:

`#cat /proc/user_beancounters`

under the VEID, you will see a lines like this:

```
889489: kmemsize 1420887 2768219 60252800 121278080 0
lockedpages 0 0 550 550 0
privvmpages 8622 18280 500000 750000 0
```

In this case, `privvmpages` is set to `500000:750000` and has no failcounts. You probably will have failcounts greater than 0. To raise privvmpages, use this command:

`vzctl set VEID --privvmpages XXXXX:YYYYY --save`

This will set VEID privvmpages to `XXXXX:YYYYY`.

If this doesn't help, use these steps and edit your post:

1. Reboot the physical server if able, in order to clear counters
2. run `cat /proc/user_beancounters` and save it
3. simulate problem
4. repeat step 2

Answer (score 0):

I think it is worth noting that it might be a hardware or software issue, so I would try and sort that out first.

Can you turn it on but disable standard processing and see if anything changes, e.g. shut down all or most processes, so that just the power supply and chip-sets are operating, but very little processing is being done.  Note this will not heat up the components as much.  So you might also need to try running something like a memory test or loop on a compression algorithm which would load the CPU and buss logic, thus causing it's circuits to come up to temperature.

If it still shuts down after 20 minutes it sounds like a thermal related hardware issue.  If you can put it in a freezer (seriously) and try to run it from there.  If it stays on then you have a bad transistor somewhere.

The basics:  bad transistors often start to fail when they get hot.  You can sometimes cool a bad (intermittent) one and get it to work.  You can also heat a bad intermittent one and get it to fail.  .. and yes, your server is just a billion transistors or so (including important high power transistors in the power supply which are the most likely ones to fail).  You can also carefully heat the mother board with a heat gun to sometimes get it fail.  A good mother board will run pretty hot and not fail, though running it hot for long periods of time will shorten it's life (see info about 'the bathtub curve').

If it does not shutdown figure out which process might be causing the issue by a process of binary divide and conquer, which is the fastest way I know of for sorting out problems.  For example try starting up about 1/2 of the processes, (the ones not dependent on other things as much).

Also you might be able to swap some of the hardware with another system, like the power supply to help sort out what is what.

(I repaired computers for a living way back when.)